# Pip install not working?

Tags: python

I've been using Ubuntu 17.04 but my pip install is not working. Pip3 works fine and I've been getting by using python3 but I want to use volatility plugins with vol.py and I need python2 for that.

pip install just runs normally and installs everything fine but when I import it it says it's not installed. And yes I've tried using pip2, python -m pip, etc-- python -m pip just gives some error about no zlib when I've already installed it (zlib package thing). Help?

Comment: Do you have python2 installed?

Comment: Make sure that pip is using the right python install (or keep using python -m pip) and see if there aren't any more zlib packages (some dev package or something? zlib1g-dev?)

Comment: I installed zlib1g-dev; I definitely have python 2.7.14 installed but when i test it in shell it wont let me import anything. I think it might be because Ubuntu comes with it preinstalled and I tried to download it from the website too when i just got it idk

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which version of python you want to use

Try this

```
    python3.6 -m pip install <package>
```

or

```
    python3 -m pip install <package>
```

Comment: yes i know the installs work on python3.6, the problem is i want to install them on python 2.7 and it doesnt work. when i do python2.7 -m pip install it throws some zlib error and if i do pip install or pip2 install it works but when i run python it says cannot import, not installed